# Anthropologist in Mars researching Martian’s sexuality

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, mars

Some years ago, no more than 5 or 6. I read a story in Asimov about a female anthropology PhD. Student doing research in Mars to try to understand sexuality in a caravan of Martians. They were named something along the lines of m’benebene.

Comment: @yser14111  IMHO it is probable that "Some years ago, no more than 5 or 6" probably means that the story was read no more than 5 or 6 years ago in in about 2011-2013.  I don't think that the "5 or 6" refers to Rosa Maria Varillas's age at the time of  reading.